# Executing JavaScript present in a web page through Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

I am working on an automated script for filling up the details of the address of a person in a webpage. Note that I did not create this webpage. So while filling up the address, there is an option for Inserting the COUNTRY. I inspected this element and found that it had the "< input= .. " tag with the class name being "ComboSelect". So it is basically a dropdown menu but it populates as I type using a JavaScript file that has been linked to it (I did not write this JS File either).

My problem is I need to ensure that the country I type has to be present in the drop-down. Now here is the interesting thing: I inspected the element, clicked on "Console" and typed the following JavaScript method:

```
ns.Fields.isFieldValid("FieldName")
```

This returns true if an only if the value I type the name of a country that is there in the list and returns false otherwise. However, I tried executing this by using the following code in Selenium:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(URL);
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("ns.Fields.isFieldValid("FieldName");
```

This gave me a reference error saying that "ns" is not defined. Now I understand that the above JS code is considered to be a new Script written by me and here ns is not defines and hence I am getting this error.

So my question is how do I get to execute the code using the already present JS in the webpage because the code works in the browser console but does not work through selenium. Is there a way for me to run the above code in the Firefox's Console and get the result of true or false from it?

Firefox : 46.0.1

Selenium : 3.4.0

Comment: Out of curiosity, normally when I use Selenium I don't execute script it at all possible. I know there are some methods for Selenium to wait for or check for the existence of DOM elements. Is it possible to know, say, the class name of the option you want to find? Then instead of executing JS via Selenium you can interact with the page/DOM to look for the option you want.

Comment: No I dont think that is possible. You see, when I load the page, there is absolutely nothing in the drop down box. The moment I start typing inside the textbox, the options start to populate. So I am not entirely sure if the country names are inside a class file at all. From what I saw there, I think the JS method is pulling the details from a JSON file resource (not available to me again) and choosing those countries that match to the letter I have typed.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. End-to-end tests are supposed to test the page or site from the perspective of a user, so I think the correct solution is to use Selenium to type into the box and let the page run the actual search. Then you can search the list itself after it populates. But as for whether or not the option exists -- that's technically a question of test data, and you "should be able to" rely on knowing what days exists for tests. Or you mock it. Alternatively, you could run manual searches on the page to see what kinds of options are available for a test.

Comment: problem is I think the original page has a separate Content Delivery System (CDS) which fills the details in before the page finishes loading. My code waits till the textbox has been populated and I immediately clear it and then fill it with a text of my own. Sometimes, Even after I type in my data, the page is still loading because of which the JS script at times gets skipped. So sometimes, the list populates but on rare occasions, the list does not populate at all so there is actually no way to determine if the country I have typed in is actually valid or not.

Comment: @RoboBear is right, you shouldn't rely on the inner implementation. That said the object `ns` is either not yet created at the time the command is executed or `ns` is wrapped in `wrappedJSObject`. Try `return window.wrappedJSObject.ns.Fields.isFieldValid('FieldName')`

Comment: Your final line is not valid. It should be `jse.executeScript("return ns.Fields.isFieldValid('FieldName')");`. It needs to have a `return` and you have nested `"`s which will cause issues. Change the inner double quotes to single and that should run... not sure if it will actually work or not though.

Comment: I also think that you should not interact with the website / single page application on a script level in end user tests. And JeffC is right, you script has errors. Possible error if `ns` is still undefined: is it possible that the application has not initialized right after the `webdriver.get()`? If it is loading other scripts asynchronously  `ns` might not have been defined yet. Determining when `ns` is available is probably possible but still bad end user testing practice.

Comment: @FlorentB. wrappedJSObject did what I wanted. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

### Discalaimer

I create an answer since it would be too long for a comment though I think your question is an example of a [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and your question is not clear enough to be answered precisely or without spending too much effort (what I probably did) and at the risk of down-/closevotes since my answer is off the actual topic (but I do this deliberately).

### Why is the scripting approach a bad idea?

Here are some reasons why is the scripting approach a bad idea *for acceptance testing*:

- The application may change any time

  Especially in the case you mentioned:

  > Note that I did not create this webpage.
- Method/functions you call may have side effects (even though the name sounds clear a function might do something else when being called)
- Real users won't interact in the way you do with scripting, you may miss

  - bugs or
  - bad user experience

(All aspects may also apply when using Selenium for non-testing automation.)

### Attempt to help

Let me summarize what I think is unclear so far:

- how does the interaction of that element look like *(I'll make some assumptions)*
- how does the DOM look like during interaction *(I'll make some assumptions)*
- what is the Selenium program used for: automation/scripting of form submission to massively create records or real end user / acceptance testing *(I assume read testing)*

But let me start assuming it's all about acceptance testing (many things also apply to pure automation too) ...

You wrote:

> I am working on an automated script for filling up the details of the address of a person in a webpage. [...] So while filling up the address, there is an option for Inserting the COUNTRY. I inspected this element and found that it had the "< input= .. " tag with the class name being "ComboSelect".

And:

> So it is basically a dropdown menu but it populates as I type [...]

I assume the interaction looks like this:

```
Country
[|            ]      Step 1 (empty input with cursor)


Country
[B|           ]      Step 2 (letter "B" entered)


Country
[Br|          ]      Step 3 (a proposal box opened)
+-------------+
|Braunschweig |
|Bremen       |
|Brandenburg  |
+-------------+


Country
[Bra|         ]      Step 4 (the proposals limited even more)
+-------------+
|Braunschweig |
|Brandenburg  |
+-------------+
```

Assumption: that combobox is either realized via a [`<select>` element with `<option>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Examples) or via a `<div>`, `<ul>` or other elements containg the list entries. (This is what you should clarify in you question actually.)

Let's assume it looks like this when "Braunschweig" was entered:

```
<input type="text" />
<div class="search-proposals country">
    <ul>
        <li>Braunschweig</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> My problem is I need to ensure that the country I type has to be present in the drop-down.

I don't see why you can't just type the country ...

```
Country
[Zoesville    ]
```

Assuming "Zoesville" does not exist.

Thus there's no entry in the proposals list. It's either empty

```
<input type="text" />
<div class="search-proposals country">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or no proposal element at all is present:

```
<input type="text" />
```

You should now be able to detect the presence of `By.cssSelector(".search-proposals.country li")`.

Of course, the application may also react with an empty or no proposal list if the entered country is *correct*. In this case that proposal element gives no indication/distinction of an correct/wrong input. The same counts for real users too: they will have a bad user experience.

Ususally there's some indication like a green check either when a valid value has been entered or at least when the field was blurred while focussing the next input. This is another element you can check for.

In case of real acceptance testing a missing validity indicator element would be worth a bug report / improvement.

But since this is speculation and so far only you know how that page works, I'll stop here.

### Some words on your comments

In the comments you wrote:

> [...] From what I saw there, I think the JS method is pulling the details from a JSON file resource (not available to me again) and choosing those countries that match to the letter I have typed.

and:

> [...] Sometimes, Even after I type in my data, the page is still loading because of which the JS script at times gets skipped. So sometimes, the list populates but on rare occasions, the list does not populate at all so there is actually no way to determine if the country I have typed in is actually valid or not.

How can you be sure that the Javascript method will give you correct results when you can't rely on the UI either? In my opinion: you can't. You should either wait for an indication that the page finished loading or attempt to interact with it just like real users would do.

### Warranty

I hope you have enough guidance now *how to deal with such a situation without using scripting*.

I'll not edit/update this answer if the problem description changes one-eighty. I consider adding updates for details on the mentioned unclear points though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was meaningful but does not address my question directly. However, I got my answer from @Florent B. wrappedJSObject did what I wanted it to do.